# CakePHP Uploader Plugin only works on one Model

Tags: cakephp, uploader

I've installed [Miles Johnson's Uploader plugin](http://milesj.me/code/cakephp/uploader#uploading-files-through-the-model) and set it up with one of my models and got it working perfectly. Very nice.

Then I went and set it up on another model with almost identical code [the only difference is the upload path] and it won't work on the second model. When I submit the form the plugin doesn't seem to notice; I get an SQL error from an attempt to insert the POST file array straight into the DB.

Here is the code. [Other than this the plugin is imported in the bootstrap]

```
public $actsAs = array( 
    'Uploader.Attachment' => array(
        'photo' => array(
            'name'      => 'formatFileName',    
            'uploadDir' => '/uploads/uses/img/',
            'dbColumn'  => 'photo',
            'maxNameLength' => 30,
            'overwrite' => true,
            'stopSave'  => true,
            'allowEmpty'    => false,
            'transforms' => array(
                array('method' => 'resize', 'width' => 240, 'dbColumn' => 'photo_thumb'))
        )
    ),
    'Uploader.FileValidation' => array(
        'fileName' => array(
            'extension' => array('gif', 'jpg', 'png', 'jpeg'),
            'required'  => true
        )
    )
    );
```

This is on the model that is not uploading and the only difference is the uploadDir.

Does the plugin only work on one model? Any clues? thnx :}

---

### Edit for extra clarity

Here is my view code:

```
echo $this->Form->create('Use', array('type' => 'file'));
echo $this->Form->input('Use.photo', array('type' => 'file'));
echo $this->Form->input('Use.desc', array('rows' => '3', 'label' => 'Description'));
echo $this->Form->end('Add to Gallery');
```

And here is my controller code:

```
public function add() { 
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {       
            $this->Use->set('user_id', $this->Auth->user('id'));        
            if ($this->Use->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Your Use has been saved.');
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Unable to add your Use.');
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Likely an issue w/ your controller code.

Comment: My controller code for both models is exactly the same [aside model names obvs] as the plugin should hook [as I understand] to the $this->Model->save()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking thru the code with Alessandro [thank you :)] I found the problem.

If you look in the View and Controller code you can see that the model is named 'Use'. This was the problem, as Use is a loaded word in PHP and I shouldn't have used it for a model name.

I renamed the model to Outcome and now the Uploader works perfectly.

Comment: hey, i too using this plugin.. i can able to store image name in database but couldn't find the image on destination directory..
Its not showing any error also.. any idea??

Comment: sorry @GirishGowda but I stopped using CakePHP not long after this so I can't be of any help.

Comment: hey, its ok i spotted it out.. anyway thanx for the reply

Answer (score 0):

The plugin doesn't work in only one model. You can add more uploader into your site.
The model seems to be good, I suggest you to see into your form to see if you have create the form in the right way into your view (is imporant to put into your form: `'type' => 'file'`
example:

```
echo $this->Form->create('Product', array ('class' => 'form', 'type' => 'file')); 
echo $this->Form->input('ModelImage.filename', array('type' => 'file'));
echo $this->Form->submit('Add Image', array('id'=>'add_image'));
echo $this->Form->end();
```

Or the problem is the name `Use` try to change the name with another

Comment: Just double checked this and the form code is correct. `echo $this->Form->create('Use', array('type' => 'file'));
echo $this->Form->input('Use.photo', array('type' => 'file'));
echo $this->Form->input('Use.desc', array('rows' => '3', 'label' => 'Description'));
echo $this->Form->end('Add to Gallery');` Do you think that my model name [Use] could  be causing a problem?

Comment: yea its a mystery to me. If you see I edited my question to add the controller code also.

Comment: $this->Form->end() creates the submit automatically. Same as in my working upload form.

Comment: WHich type has the column 'photo' in your database?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18366/discussion-between-iiz-and-alessandro-minoccheri)